# Facebook Posted image shared link not working?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When we post image on facebook by my android app it's post successfully but when we click on that post on Facebook app (on mobile devices) there is a toast appear "**There's a problem opening this app.**" but when open in WEB and click on that posted image it'll redirect to shared link successfully.
I have use this code to share post on facebook.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "me/feed", null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                            //checkPostStatusAndEnableButton();

                        }
                    });
            Bundle postParams = request.getParameters();
            postParams.putString("link",post_url);
            postParams.putString("caption", caption);

            request.setParameters(postParams);
            request.executeAsync();
```

Is we have use some other action for url for mobile devices?

Comment: I have solved that problem,I don't have enable deep linking switch button in Facebook console .

Answer (score 0):

Try this on :

```
private static List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_photos","user_videos", "email","user_likes","user_posts",
                                                "user_hometown", "user_location","user_about_me","user_birthday",
                                                "user_friends","user_relationship_details");

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess registerCallback");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onCancel registerCallback");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Log.i(TAG,"onError registerCallback");
                    }
         });
```

Then call this share link method :

```
private void shareLink() {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                .build();
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
    }
```